# NextJS & TypeScript Module parse failed: unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js

I've got a NextJS site running TypeScript and a component of it in a separate repo installed using npm, but when I try and use the component in the site it shows the following message:

```bash
error - ./node_modules/promotion-spot/dist/PromotionSpot/Conditional/index.jsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

The component works fine when it isn't in a separate npm dependency but, when it is, NextJS won't load it properly. The component is compiled into JavaScript with `.d.ts` files and I saw that [react-chrono](https://github.com/prabhuignoto/react-chrono) does something similar and that works in the site fine.

The component's source code is at https://github.com/Relucent-Software/promotion-spot.

Here's the `package.json` file for the NextJS site too:

```json
{
  "name": "thederbyinn.co.uk",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "npm-run-all test:*",
    "test:eslint": "eslint --ext .ts --ext .js --ext .tsx --ext .jsx src/**/*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-gtm-module": "^2.0.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.53",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "luxon": "^2.4.0",
    "next": "^12.1.6",
    "next-seo": "^4.29.0",
    "promotion-spot": "github:Relucent-Software/promotion-spot",
    "query-string": "^7.1.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-chrono": "^1.15.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-masonry-css": "^1.0.16",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "schema-dts": "^1.1.0",
    "swiper": "^7.4.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
    "@types/lodash.get": "^4.4.7",
    "@types/lodash.has": "^4.5.7",
    "@types/luxon": "^2.3.2",
    "@types/node": "16.11.7",
    "@types/react": "17.0.35",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^4.4.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.23.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.23.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.5.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.13",
    "typescript": "4.4.4"
  }
}
```